# Create DateTimeOffset 00:01 / 23:59 from given DateTimeOffset for same day

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetimeoffset

Warning - TSQL newbie question ahead:

I've got a `DateTimeOffset` for, say, `2013-03-11 11:04:26.0000000 +00:00` and I need to create two new dates for the same day, one at 00:01 and another one at 23:59.

So far I've tried various things with `DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS` and `DATEPART` but it seems way to awkward - is there a simple solution to *snip off* the hours/minutes/etc. and just use the day replacing the time with the two required ones?

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server) , maybe it's useful.

Comment: Rather than computing such odd dates - if they're for comparison purposes, it would be better to change the comparison operation (i.e. people frequently try to get the "last moment" of a particular day, ignoring that things can happen *during* the last minute (or second) of the day, and so 23:59 won't include such events). Using `<` the next day, rather than `<=` 23:59 is a better solution.

Comment: Unfortunately we're supposed to create those date times to represent a time window for some other part of the application - no comparison involved at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can try this option

```
DECLARE @date datetimeoffset = '2013-03-11 11:04:26.0000000 +00:00'
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0 , @date), '00:01'), 
       DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0 , @date), '23:59') 

--Results:2013-03-11 00:01:00.000   2013-03-11 23:59:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it...

```
select @pkgDate = CONVERT (date, @pkgDate)

select DATEADD (minute, 1, @pkgDate)
select DATEADD(hour, 23, DATEADD (minute, 59, @pkgDate))
```

..better/more concise ways of doing it still appreciated.