# Select Records for which the date field is spent a year

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with columns

```
 TypeExame, DateExame
```

How can I select all records with (Now-DateExame) > = 365 days?

Answer (score 4):

```
select *
from MyTable
where datediff (day, DateExame, getdate()) >= 365
```

See [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) and [GETDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) for further details.

Comment: Tank, Ica to create a dinamic date ??

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand - you can just change `getdate()`, i.e. the current server date, to whatever date you need.

Comment: Let me calculate Datediff (day, DateBird, Dateserial (31.12, year)) 
But Dateserial is not implemented in SQLHow do I do this where the year is passed in as a parameter How do I do this

Comment: See http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/15788/10-ways-to-simulate-dateserial-function.aspx for numerous approaches. If you still need more help it's probably best to ask a new question as it's different from your original question and it's best to avoid long conversations in comments where possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an index on `DateExame`, putting the condition like this will enable its usage:

```
SELECT *
FROM atable
WHERE DateExame <= DATEADD(DAY, -365, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
;
```

The above references the `date` data type, which means you'd need at least SQL Server 2008 to run that. To make it work in earlier versions, you could rewrite the condition like this:

```
WHERE DateExame <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) - 365, 0)
```

Basically, the modified version uses [the DATEADD/DATEDIFF method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server) of truncating a `datetime` value with a minor tweak to also subtract 365 days along the way.

However, if all your `DateExame` values are dates without the time part, this simpler version should work just as well:

```
WHERE DateExame <= DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE())
```

That is, removal of `GETDATE()`'s result's time part would be perfectly unnecessary.

Comment: Only one solution of all presented that uses Sargable predicate.Veeery nice, bro!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
select *
from MyTable
where datediff (day, DateExame, getdate()) >= 365
```

By Using Datediff function you can subtract two dates . you can pass first argument as minute , day , month , year etc .