# Select dates inside current month SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table similar to one below. I'm trying to select only the rows where the Start Date is in the current month. Here is what I have so far, but it's not working.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE StartDate = MONTH(getdate())
```

How can I select only the values where the start date is in the current month?

[image]

Comment: datetime is the datatype

Comment: Why accept a downvoted and discredited answer? Do you not care about performance or scalability?

Comment: First attempt worked had not been back, accepted your answer for performance and scalability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this construct to avoid functions on the StartDate columns (like MONTH or YEAR). These functions will prevent any index or statistics being used/

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE
  StartDate >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
 AND StartDate < DATEADD(month, 1+DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Any answer that puts a function on StartDate will not scale as expected. See [error number 2 here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/ten-common-sql-programming-mistakes/). The filter is now non-sargable, and index/statistics can't be used. Every row will be looked at for a table scan.

Comment: Personally I prefer `DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, Current_Timestamp) + 1, 0)` as this puts the `+1` as part of the `DateAdd()` which makes it a bit clearer in my opinion. Other than that, best answer here :)

Comment: @gbn can you explain so I can understand for future use?

Comment: The query optimiser needs to see "raw data" (without functions or processing) to generate a good query plan. So instead of using MONTH() and YEAR() we change it to a ranged search. The DATEADD/DATEDIFF is an efficient way to find start of week/month/day etc as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/1177529/27535 (and following links)

Answer (score -1):

You need to check the month of both fields

```
WHERE MONTH(startdate) = MONTH(getdate())
```

Comment: Looks like I forgot that part, but the questions has already been answered.