# CONVERTING TO_DATE FROM ORACLE TO SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am migrating my oracle database to SQL Server. I'm in need of some help converting this one line of code in my `WHERE` clause

```
TO_DATE(TBL_TMX_ATTEMPT.LSTUPD) > (SYSDATE - '5')
```

Comment: `SYSDATE - '5'` is not a good style in the first place. `'5'` is a character literal, not a number. You should always use the correct literals. `5` is a number. Btw: Why are you storing a date in a `varchar` column? If you are migrating you should also take the chance to use the correct datatype and store that in a `date` or `datetime` column. Storing a date in a character column is a really bad choice.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I should think "date - 5" is bad form, anyway. You're subtracting 5 what? Days? Months? Years? I guess if you've been working with Oracle a long time, you would probably know, but not everyone does. Better to make it clear. On a side note, when I see `LSTUPD`, I can't help but think it's supposed to read, "L-stupid."

Comment: @jpmc26: the meaning of `date - 5` is well defined and documented in Oracle (it's days). It's the same in other DBMS (Postgres, Firebird, H2 also work that way). But I agree: using a standard interval `date - interval '5' day` is probably clearer and more portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

`WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,TBL_TMX_ATTEMPT.LSTUPD) > GETDATE()-5`

If LSTUPD is already in a datetime, then omit the CONVERT().  No need to run the conversion if it is already IN the right format.

Also keep in mind GETDATE() includes a time stamp.  So this is the current date/time - 5 days.

If you want to get 5 days before midnight use this:

`WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,TBL_TMX_ATTEMPT.LSTUPD) > CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120))-5`

Comment: Thanks JiggsJedi, I used the first one but without the convert and it worked great. I forgot that the Oracle code needed to convert the date to a string eventually. I do not need to do that in my sql version, just running the query

Comment: I would have upvoted if not for using string manipulation to remove the time. Other approaches can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server.

Answer (score 1):

```
CONVERT(datetime,TBL_TMX_ATTEMPT.LSTUPD) > DATEADD(DAY,-5,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know what the data type of TBL_TMX_ATTEMPT.LSTUPD is. If it is a VARCHAR2 or other string type (BAD choice for storing dates, btw), you need to take the date formats into consideration when calling CONVERT in SQL Server. Look up the Date/Time Style parameter of the CONVERT function for more info.

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```