# Limit SQL results to last 7 days

Tags: sql

I have a simple SQL query that looks like this...

```
SELECT 
    COUNT (* )
AS
    count
FROM
    wlead
WHERE
    f_id = '765'
```

This works great but I would now like to limit the query to just return results from the last 7 days.  There is a field called date_created which is formatted like this...

```
2014-10-12 11:31:26
```

Is there an automatic way of limiting the results or do I need to work out the date 7 days previous first?

Comment: What database is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't mention your DBMS, the following is ANSI SQL:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from wlead
where f_id = '765'
  and date_created >= current_date - interval '7' day;
```

If `date_created` is actually a timestamp, you might want to compare that to a timestamp as well:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from wlead
where f_id = '765'
  and date_created >= current_timestamp - interval '7' day;
```

Note that this does not take care of "removing" the time part. `current_timestamp - interval '7' day` will yield a timestamp 7 days a ago at the same time (e.g. 20:52)

To "ignore" the time part you could cast `date_created` to a `date`:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from wlead
where f_id = '765'
  and cast(date_created as date) >= current_date - interval '7' day;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can use [the `DATEADD()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and [the `GETDATE()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) for this.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    wlead
WHERE
    f_id = '765' AND
    date_created >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
```

Please note that this will return records created exactly seven days ago (so, if run now, records created after 2:45 PM EST). If you need to return everything from midnight on, you could use this to [strip out the time portion and return midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    wlead
WHERE
    f_id = '765' AND
    date_created >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()) -7, 0)
```

Comment: How do you know which database he uses ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming mysql

```
..AND date_created<= NOW() AND date_created>= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will like this:

```
... WHERE DATEDIFF(getdate(), date_created) <= 7
```