# MS SQL query between (today) and 30 days ago

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

Microsoft SQL 2008 (using Visual Studio 2010 to build and test query).

Query function:  This query is going to be run via batch file in Windows Task Scheduler.  The goal is to be able to create a CSV file every month.

My query:

```
SELECT     TYPE, DATEX, TIME, STREET, CROSS_ST, XCOORD, YCOORD
FROM       INCIDENT
WHERE      (TYPE = '644') OR
           (TYPE = '459') OR
           (TYPE = 'HS') OR
           (TYPE = '484') OR
           (TYPE = '487') OR
           (TYPE = '488') OR
           (TYPE = '10851') OR
           (TYPE = '187') OR
           (TYPE = '211') OR
           (TYPE = '245') OR
           (TYPE = '451')
ORDER BY DATEX
```

I am trying to sort the 'DATEX' column (which is in datetime format) between 'today's date' and '30 days ago'

I have tried all of these statements and none of them work:

```
(DATEX < DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE()))

DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 
(
CONVERT(varchar, DATEX, 110) AS DATE,
    DATEX CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(d,-30,GETDATE()), 23)     
    )
```

*ERROR INTERVAL is not recognized

```
AND DATEX BETWEEN DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(mm,1,GETDATE())
```

*error unrecognized syntax 1

```
=DateAdd("d", -7, Today())     *Today is not a recognized function
where date_col > DATEADD(day,-7,SYSDATETIME())
```

*unrecognized syntax near 'Where'

```
where DATEDIFF(day,date_col,SYSDATETIME()) < 7
```

*error near 'WHERE'

```
 DATEX Dte <  DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())
```

*an expression of non-Boolean type specified

```
AND (DATEX BETWEEN ({ fn CURDATE() }, 30) AND { fn CURDATE() })
```

*incorrect syntax near ','

**What is the correct syntax for Microsoft SQL query to sort a table 'incident' between *'today's date'* and *'30 days ago'?***

*Please note that simply using `Between 'YYYY-MM-DD' and 'YYYY-MM-DD'` is not helpful because I would need to manually change the dates to run the query. I want to automate it to create a CSV file every month.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of throwing everything at the wall and seeing what sticks, I strongly recommend **reading the vendor's documentation**.  Microsoft SQL Server has extremely comprehensive and readable documentation, even among RDBMSs, both on the web and if you install the fantastic [SQL Server Books Online](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1054).

As to your issue, you'll need to use `DATEADD()`.  The problem, however, is that datetime fields and `GETDATE()` have a time component, and you need to account for that.

So, one of the keys you'll need to know, is how to strip the time from a datetime.  If you're on SQL Server 2008 R2 and higher, you can do this:

```
CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

But that doesn't work on SQL Server 2008 and earlier.  Instead, you need to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server):

```
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

If you know that DATEX is never in the future, you can use this:

```
SELECT TYPE, DATEX, TIME, STREET, CROSS_ST, XCOORD, YCOORD
FROM INCIDENT
WHERE TYPE IN ('644','459','HS','484','487','488','10851','187','211','245','451')
    AND DATEX >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 30, 0) 
ORDER BY DATEX
```

Which is, "DATEX is on or after midnight 30 days ago."

Now, if DATEX might be in the future, but it always has a zero time value, you can use this:

```
SELECT TYPE, DATEX, TIME, STREET, CROSS_ST, XCOORD, YCOORD
FROM INCIDENT
WHERE TYPE IN ('644','459','HS','484','487','488','10851','187','211','245','451')
    AND DATEX BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 30, 0) AND GETDATE()
ORDER BY DATEX
```

Which is, "DATEX is on or after midnight 30 days ago and on or before right now."  On the other hand, if DATEX might be in the future and will have a non-zero time component, you should use this:

```
SELECT TYPE, DATEX, TIME, STREET, CROSS_ST, XCOORD, YCOORD
FROM INCIDENT
WHERE TYPE IN ('644','459','HS','484','487','488','10851','187','211','245','451')
    AND DATEX >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 30, 0) 
    AND DATEX <  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
ORDER BY DATEX
```

This is "DATEX is on or after midnight 30 days ago and before midnight tomorrow."  It's easier to refer to "before midnight tomorrow" because datetime can have fractional seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dateadd` Function also remove the multiple `OR` conditions and use `IN` clause

```
SELECT     TYPE, DATEX, TIME, STREET, CROSS_ST, XCOORD, YCOORD
FROM       INCIDENT
WHERE      DATEX BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-30,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
AND        TYPE in ('644','459','HS','484','487','488','10851','187','211','245','451')
ORDER BY DATEX
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be something like this

```
SELECT     TYPE, DATEX, TIME, STREET, CROSS_ST, XCOORD, YCOORD
FROM       INCIDENT
WHERE      DATEX > DATEADD(dd, -30, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS INT) AS DATETIME)) AND
           ((TYPE = '644') OR
            (TYPE = '459') OR
            (TYPE = 'HS') OR
            (TYPE = '484') OR
            (TYPE = '487') OR
            (TYPE = '488') OR
            (TYPE = '10851') OR
            (TYPE = '187') OR
            (TYPE = '211') OR
            (TYPE = '245') OR
            (TYPE = '451'))
ORDER BY DATEX
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad1de/2) you can find a working demo

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your condition.

```
WHERE DATEX BETWEEN GETDATE()-30 AND GETDATE()
```

it will minus 30 days off from todays date