# dateadd() is not working as desired to find the date of 7 days from now sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I am trying to find the date of 7 days from a specific date. To do this I tried

```
Select @Fromdate = DATEADD(day,-7, max(last_update)), @todate= max(last_update)
FROM vwABC
```

But it is not working and when I tried the following every thing works fine.

```
SELECT @Fromdate = '20150601', @ToDate = MAX(last_update)
FROM vwABC
```

I cant understand, whats the problem. Please help.

Comment: "But it is not working", can you be more specific?, what doesn't work?

Comment: And also, tell us what the value of `last_update` is, and what you are expecting to get back.

Comment: "7 days from now" would more likely be `DATEADD(day,7` than `DATEADD(day,-7` but without more context, it's difficult to know what you're trying to do.

Comment: What behavior are you expecting, and what behavior do you get?

Comment: Try this Query first and check are you getting your desired Date or not

Select DATEADD(day,-7, max(last_update)) FROM vwABC

Comment: "7 days from now" I meant 7 days ago so I think -7 is fine. On the basis of it i am calculating an activity which is counted as 0 when i use dateadd but if i use plan  20150601, it gets the value.

Comment: I am getting the desired date.

Comment: @Asbat then nothing is wrong in the code you posted here, you might doing mistake somewhere else

Comment: That is very strange, so I found that if the time portion is included then the calculations are 0. When I tried ATfromdate = 2015-05-23 00:00:00.000 I got results 0. when I tried ATfromdate 2015-05-23 I got the correct results. I have some datediff methods down there to calculate results, which may get confused. Any suggestions how to truncate the time part from the dateadd before assigning to ATfromdate

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me through this reference [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

```
Select @Fromdate = convert(date, DATEADD(day,-7, max(last_update)),101),  @todate= max(last_update) FROM vwABC
```