# converting datetime with out the time in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert the datetime output into a date only and i would like to have it in this format:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

what am i doing wrong here:

```
    select 
    DATEADD(DAY,  CONVERT(INT,(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dt) - 1)) * -1,dt) as [WeekBeginDate],
    SUM(hours) AS TOTAL_HOURS
    from myTable
    where
    uid = 'myUID' and dt >= CAST(DATEADD(WEEK,-5,DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) - 1) * -1,GETDATE())) AS date) group by DATEADD(DAY,  CONVERT(INT,(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dt) - 1)) * -1,dt) order by 1
```

Comment: Do U want to convert  field `dt` to format `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use format 101 for convert:

```
select convert(varchar(10), dt, 101)
```

If you want the week begging date using your expression:

```
select convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(DAY,  CONVERT(INT,(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dt) - 1)) * -1,dt), 101) as [WeekBeginDate]
```