# Dates while querying not returning proper output in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query when I run like this

```
select emp_name, dt_of_join 
from emp_mst 
where dt_of_join = '2015-09-14'
```

I get one record from the table.

But when I try to run in dynamically like below

```
SELECT emp_name, Dt_Of_Join 
FROM emp_mst 
WHERE Dt_Of_Join =  DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
```

it doesn't return any records. WHY ???

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: GetDate() returns a `datetime` instead of a `date`. Is Dt_Of_Join a datetime field filled with only dates? You could try the following: `DATEADD(month, -6, cast(GETDATE() as date))`

Comment: Also, you might want to do a `select getdate()` just to verify that the date is correct on your server.

Comment: @Me.Name: `Dt_Of_Join` is `datetime` dataype and ur solution also didn't worked giving error as `Type date is not a defined system type.`

Comment: @ZoharPeled: after your suggestion it gives as `2016-03-14 18:19:29.993` i guess it is working

Comment: If the row you get back with `2015-09-14` has a time between 00:00:00 and 18:19:29 @Me.Name is probably right. You have to keep in mind, that DATETIME values carry a time and today at 18:19 minus 6 months is then at 18:19...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `getdate()` return a time value with hours, which makes the times to be not equal. Use `CAST AS DATE` to trunc the date like this:

```
SELECT emp_name, Dt_Of_Join 
FROM emp_mst 
WHERE Dt_Of_Join =  cast(DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

**EDIT:** `DATE` was introduced in SQL Server 2008, if you are using an older version, try this:

```
SELECT emp_name, Dt_Of_Join 
FROM emp_mst 
WHERE Dt_Of_Join = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

As mentioned in the comments by @zoharpeled , you can read about the approaches to trunc a time value from dates [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: getting error as `Type DATE is not a defined system type.`

Comment: yes, tried that and is working, but what is `FLOOR` and why `FLOAT` is used ?

Comment: Its another way of triming the time value, what error are you getting? @coder

Comment: no, not any error now, It is working fine and expected output is coming. Thanks a lot

Comment: You might also want to add a link to [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)