# SQL query not returning correct date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a simple view created in VS 2017. Here it is:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ApplicantStat]
    AS SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()), '') AS ID,
    ISNULL(AVG(ApplicationTime), 0) AS 'AvgApplicationTime',
    ISNULL(AVG(ResponseTime), 0) AS 'AvgResponseTime',
    ISNULL(CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN [IsAccepted] = 1 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(CASE WHEN [IsValid] = 1 THEN 1 END) AS float), 0) AS 'PctAccepted'
    FROM [Application]
    WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE()-30 AS date) AND CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS date)
```

As you can see, it gets data between 2 dates and does some simple aggregation.

The idea of the cast is that I want to ignore the time and get everything for the date range regardless - so as of today, 15th Mar, I would it to fetch everything for 14th March 00:00:00 - 23:59:59 and 29 days previous.

This does not happen - it picks up 3 rows (13th) - it should pick up all 5 rows. And yes, my system date is currently 15/03/2018 14:44 (UK time).

Here's, the table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application] (
    [Id]              INT            NOT NULL,
    [ApplicantId]     INT            NOT NULL,
    [LoanAmount]      INT            NOT NULL,
    [LoanTerm]        SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
    [EmailAddress]    VARCHAR (254)  NOT NULL,
    [MobilePhone]     VARCHAR (11)   NOT NULL,
    [House]           VARCHAR (25)   NOT NULL,
    [Street]          VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [TownCity]        VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Postcode]        VARCHAR (7)    NOT NULL,
    [IpAddress]       VARCHAR (39)   NOT NULL,
    [IsValid]         BIT            NOT NULL,
    [IsAccepted]      BIT            NOT NULL,
    [Commission]      DECIMAL (9, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Processors]      VARCHAR (500)  NOT NULL,
    [ResponseTime]    SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationTime] SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn]       DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Application] ([Id], [ApplicantId], [LoanAmount], [LoanTerm], [EmailAddress], [MobilePhone], [House], [Street], [TownCity], [Postcode], [IpAddress], [IsValid], [IsAccepted], [Commission], [Processors], [ResponseTime], [ApplicationTime], [CreatedOn]) VALUES (1, 1, 300, 3, N'john.doe@tmail.com', N'07957000000', N'1', N'Acacia Avenue', N'Suburbia', N'SB1 2RB', N'100.100.100.100', 1, 1, CAST(3.20 AS Decimal(9, 2)), N'1,2,3,4,5', 90, 600, N'2018-03-13 08:00:00')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Application] ([Id], [ApplicantId], [LoanAmount], [LoanTerm], [EmailAddress], [MobilePhone], [House], [Street], [TownCity], [Postcode], [IpAddress], [IsValid], [IsAccepted], [Commission], [Processors], [ResponseTime], [ApplicationTime], [CreatedOn]) VALUES (2, 2, 500, 12, N'a@b.com', N'0', N'1', N'a', N's', N's', N'1', 0, 1, CAST(5.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)), N'1', 60, 300, N'2018-03-14 16:00:00')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Application] ([Id], [ApplicantId], [LoanAmount], [LoanTerm], [EmailAddress], [MobilePhone], [House], [Street], [TownCity], [Postcode], [IpAddress], [IsValid], [IsAccepted], [Commission], [Processors], [ResponseTime], [ApplicationTime], [CreatedOn]) VALUES (3, 3, 1000, 6, N'a@b.com', N'0', N'1', N'a', N's', N's', N'1', 1, 1, CAST(7.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)), N'1', 75, 360, N'2018-03-13 10:00:00')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Application] ([Id], [ApplicantId], [LoanAmount], [LoanTerm], [EmailAddress], [MobilePhone], [House], [Street], [TownCity], [Postcode], [IpAddress], [IsValid], [IsAccepted], [Commission], [Processors], [ResponseTime], [ApplicationTime], [CreatedOn]) VALUES (4, 4, 2000, 24, N'a@b.com', N'0', N'1', N'a', N's', N's', N'1', 1, 1, CAST(20.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)), N'1', 30, 365, N'2018-03-14 11:00:00')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Application] ([Id], [ApplicantId], [LoanAmount], [LoanTerm], [EmailAddress], [MobilePhone], [House], [Street], [TownCity], [Postcode], [IpAddress], [IsValid], [IsAccepted], [Commission], [Processors], [ResponseTime], [ApplicationTime], [CreatedOn]) VALUES (5, 5, 3000, 18, N'a@b.com', N'0', N'1', N'a', N's', N's', N'1', 1, 1, CAST(40.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)), N'1', 45, 330, N'2018-03-13 12:00:00')
```

Comment: Cannot create sample data in my local: Foreign key 'FK_Application_ToTable' references invalid table 'dbo.Applicant'.

Comment: Why you you expect id 2 and 4 to return? `'2018-03-14T16:00:00.000'` and `'2018-03-14T11:00:00.000'` is **AFTER** `'2018-03-14T00:00:00.000'`, thus does not meet the requirement of your `WHERE` clause (which is effectively `BETWEEN '2018-02-13T00:00:00.000' AND '2018-03-14T00:00:00.000'`)

Comment: You have filtered out the rows for March 14 because of your date logic. Here is what your predicate values are. select CAST(GETDATE()-30 AS date), CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS date). BTW, you should be careful using math against dates. It is preferred to use DATEADD. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: Or just CAST CreatedOn to a date, too.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli - sorry, thought I'd got rid of it. Amended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

```
WHERE 
    CreatedOn >= CAST(GETDATE()-30 AS date) AND 
    CreatedOn < CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
```

The problem is your converting to date the day before today.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the user here hasn't used `CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS date)`. They don't have the `-1` in their query. (they've done the correct syntax and used `>=` and then `<`).

Comment: @Larnu I have no idea what you are saying but I don't think it's right. The query posted by the OP surely shows that exact expression in their where clause.

Comment: @JacobH in the link that Juan has provided, they have `CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS date) as dt3`. That isn't the syntax that Ezequiel has used. (my comment is about the answer, as we are in the comments of an answer, not the question ;) )

Comment: @Larnu Yeah I'm still not following you. The only difference is the column alias. Juan is saying "this is how you would debug".

Comment: @JacobH Have a look at the link posted by Juan. If it doesn;'t make sense, it seems there is some kind of language barrier here, as I really cannot explain more clearly. than stating the obvious (`CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS date)` and `CAST(GETDATE() AS date)` is not the same)

Comment: @JacobH Yes, my bad. I should had make clear the Ezequiel answer is correct and my test code is to show OP why his answer wasn't working in first place.

Answer (score 3):

You can `CAST` your `CreatedOn` field as `DATE` to remove the time portion, which is getting in your way here...

Perhaps

```
WHERE CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE()-30 AS date) AND CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS date)
```

**BUT** - `CAST`ing a field in the WHERE expression *may* make it non SARGable. See [here](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2016/09/13/what-is-a-sargable-predicate/).  So avoid this solution for large or production environments unless you know the expression will be SARGable.  Use only as a test to refine your logic and options.  (Even if there is no explicit index on CreatedOn - it *may* still suffer as SQL builds its own indexes all the time if no index exists explicitly. 
 Always worth confirming whether it is SARGable so you know for sure.)

To see what is happening - view your values in your SELECT - just to get an idea of what is working

For example:

```
SELECT TOP 1000
CreatedOn 
,CAST(GETDATE()-30 AS date)
,CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS date)
FROM [Application]
```

Or see the other options for removing time values from datatime fields [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)
as you may want to coerce or round the time value instead

Comment: Don't do this; converting your column to a `date` makes the query non-SARGable.

Comment: @Larnu Good point thanks.  I will leave the answer as it might help the OP work through options using different techniques... But I will add that point to my answer

Comment: @Larnu actually converting a datetime to a date IS one of those rare times where a function in the where predicate is sargable, but not always a good idea. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to ignore the time value, just make sure that your search terms are accurate for it. Also, don't blindly add things like `ISNULL` to every column. Spend a few seconds thinking if it's relevant or not. `NEWID()` for example, is never going to return a `NULL` value to you. Adding that kind of code is poor programming which will lead to less legible code.

Here's how I would write it to account for the time portions:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ApplicantStat
AS
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()) AS ID,
    COALESCE(AVG(ApplicationTime), 0) AS AvgApplicationTime,
    COALESCE(AVG(ResponseTime), 0) AS AvgResponseTime,
    COALESCE(CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN [IsAccepted] = 1 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(CASE WHEN [IsValid] = 1 THEN 1 END) AS float), 0) AS PctAccepted
FROM
    dbo.Application
WHERE
    CreatedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND
    CreatedOn <  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```