# How can I group by time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Query Group By Datetime problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693619/sql-query-group-by-datetime-problem)

I am working on an application with 2 steps.

- Scan logs and persist data from them in a database.
- Read data from database and visualize the data.

The first step is more or less finished. I try to explain the background and my reguirement with the second step.

Each row in the database consists of some info like logdate, logfilename, LogType, logMessage etc. So I want for example write SQL that summarize a given LogType per day.

This is the columns:

```
[LogDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Computer] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Type] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[FileName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[LineNo] [int] NOT NULL,
[UserName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Message] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
```

I imagine the output could be like this if I want to show all rows with Type=TDBError:

```
Date        Sum
2012-10-01  3
2012-10-02  12
2012-10-03  40
2012-10-05  24
2012-10-06  18
```

So at date 2012-10-01 there was 3 rows in DB where Type=TDBError. At date 2012-10-02 there was 12 etc.

How should I write the SQL for this ?

Comment: So you don't want a row for 10-04 with a sum of 0? Also, please specify the version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2008 or newer:

```
SELECT 
  [Date] = CONVERT(DATE, LogDate), 
  [Sum] = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Log_Table_Name
WHERE [Type] = 'DBError'
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, LogDate)
ORDER BY [Date];
```

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY DATEPART(day, date), DATEPART(month, date), DATEPART(year, date)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a group by the parts of the time

```
GROUP BY date(log_date), month(log_date), day(log_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Cast(FLOOR(CAST(DATE as float)) as DateTime) as Date,COUNT(*) as [SUM]
from Log_Table_Name
Group by Cast(FLOOR(CAST(DATE as float)) as DateTime)
order by Cast(FLOOR(CAST(DATE as float)) as DateTime)
```

Comment: Just FYI, all those converts are not free, and I've proven that (albeit in some cases only slightly) a native convert to date is the fastest approach : http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime & http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time