# How can I group by arbitary time period with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is similar but not equal to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14367174/55007)
That was about how to summarize log-items per day.
I use this SQL.

```
SELECT 
  [DateLog] = CONVERT(DATE, LogDate), 
  [Sum] = COUNT(*)
FROM PerfRow
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, LogDate)
ORDER BY [DateLog];
```

Now I want to improve that to summarize over an arbitary time period.
So instead of sum per day, sum per hour or 5 minutes.
Is this possible ?

I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I removed the Delphi related tags, because your question has absolutely no content related to Delphi. It's strictly a SQL Server question. Please only add tags that are actually applicable to the question being asked. Thanks.

Comment: How will you decide which five minute or how will u decide 1 hour? can it be like from 1:10 am to 2:10 am like this or it will be always like 1 am  to 2 am like that..

Comment: How do you intend to represent the time period?

Comment: It is enough with 1 am to 2am. And I would like to present them as chart columns in a diagram in a Delphi application.

Answer (score 2):

You can round LogDate using DATEADD and DATEPART and then group by that.

Example (groups by five second intervals):

```
SELECT 
  [DateLog] = DATEADD(ms,((DATEPART(ss, LogDate)/5)*5000)-(DATEPART(ss, LogDate)*1000)-DATEPART(ms, LogDate), LogDate), 
  [Sum] = COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
    SELECT LogDate = '2013-01-01 00:00:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT LogDate = '2013-01-01 00:00:04' UNION ALL
    SELECT LogDate = '2013-01-01 00:00:06' UNION ALL
    SELECT LogDate = '2013-01-01 00:00:08' UNION ALL
    SELECT LogDate = '2013-01-01 00:00:10'
) a
GROUP BY DATEADD(ms,((DATEPART(ss, LogDate)/5)*5000)-(DATEPART(ss, LogDate)*1000)-DATEPART(ms, LogDate), LogDate)
```