# SQL datetime format to date only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

I am trying to select the DeliveryDate from sql database as just date. In the database, i am saving it as datetime format. How is it possible to get just date??

```
SELECT Subject, DeliveryDate 
from Email_Administration 
where MerchantId =@ MerchantID
```

03/06/2011 12:00:00 Am just be selected as 03/06/2011..

Thanks  alot in advance! :)

Comment: What RDBMS and Version? And is your desired format `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: My desired format us mm/dd/yyyy. I am a newbie for SQL, i have no idea how i can find the RDBMS type and version. All i know is SQL server 2005.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-sql-server-to-get-date-from-datetime and others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the time portion of a datetime value (SQL Server)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/how-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After perusing your previous questions I eventually determined you are probably on SQL Server 2005. [For US format you would use style 101](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDateTimeFormats.aspx)

```
select Subject, 
       CONVERT(varchar,DeliveryDate,101) as DeliveryDate
from Email_Administration 
where MerchantId =@MerchantID
```

Answer (score 24):

try the following as there will be no varchar conversion

```
SELECT Subject, CAST(DeliveryDate AS DATE)
from Email_Administration 
where MerchantId =@ MerchantID
```

Comment: This is better than CONVERT(varchar,FIELD,103) as [DD/MM/YYYY]

Comment: What I did was `LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DeliveryDate, 126), 10)` because I needed the date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 4):

With SQL server you can use this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY];
```

with mysql server you can do the following

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE YEAR(date_field) = '2006' AND MONTH(date_field) = '9' AND DAY(date_field) = '11'

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Subject, CONVERT(varchar(10),DeliveryDate) as DeliveryDate
from Email_Administration 
where MerchantId =@ MerchantID
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function, do the conversion/formatting to "date" in the function passing in the original datetime value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.convert_varchar_datetime_to_date (@iOriginal_datetime varchar(max) = '')
RETURNS date
AS BEGIN
    declare @sReturn date

    set @sReturn = convert(date, @iOriginal_datetime)

    return @sReturn
END
```

Now call the function from the view:

```
    select dbo.convert_varchar_datetime_to_date(original_datetime) as dateOnlyValue
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using SQL Server use **convert**

e.g. `select convert(varchar(10), DeliveryDate, 103) as ShortDate`

more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx