# Temporarily change format of a date column in SQL Query output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am pulling data from SQL Server, and the date on our back end is formatted prtty ugly, like so:

```
2014-01-10 00:00:00.000
```

I was wondering if there is some sort of funciton that I can run in my query to display the date column differently in my output? I don't want to actually alter the way in which the Column is formatted on the back end, I just want to change how it is presented to the user in the results of a sigle query.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: I am using SQL server 2008 R2 as my RDBMS

Comment: which sql product you are using and version as well?

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222075/sql-datetime-format-to-date-only

Comment: What do you want the date to look like?  There are many different types of output.

Comment: Lol I guess I never thought about it? Anything is better than the way it is now. How about the standard MM/DD/YYYY format?

Comment: Alternatively, you can format on the client.  If your query is part of an app written in .net, coldfusion, java, etc, they all have date formatting functions.

Comment: @AdamJ, your standard is not necessarily other people's standard.  Just specify the desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format datetime output using the `CONVERT` function.  Review the [MSDN documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and the [W3Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) for the Convert function for more details and examples.

Here is quick example of a few different formats available.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE())
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),10)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),110)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(),106)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(),113)
```

Results:

```
Feb 27 2014 11:54AM 
02-27-14
02-27-2014
27 Feb 2014
27 Feb 2014 11:54:33:977
```

Answer (score 1):

**SQL 2012: Has `FORMAT()`:**

```
SELECT FORMAT(Date_Field,'ddd, MM yyyy')
```

Here's a list of [FORMAT() options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

**Prior to SQL 2012:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),Date_Field,109)
```

List of [CONVERT() styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

If you just want to remove the time portion you can:

```
SELECT CAST(Date_Field AS DATE)
```