# Using Date datatype for removing time info from GetDate() is ok?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, getdate

Typically I need to remove time info from `GETDATE()`. I need this because I have some DateTime fields where I know I am storing only date information so to make reliable comparisons (`MyDate < GETDATE()`) I need to remove time information from `GETDATE()`). Of course I could use the `DATE` datatype in `MyDate`, but this is ok for new applications, not for legacy ones.

I used to do it with `CAST`, but since in SQL Server 2008 there is also the `DATE` datatype it seems more readable.

Old approach

```
DECLARE @Today DateTime
SET @Today =  (CAST(FLOOR(CAST( GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
select @Today
```

New approach

```
DECLARE @TodayDate Date
Set @TodayDate = GETDATE()
select @TodayDate
```

May I go with the second or is there any caveat? (of coruse I use 2008 only!)

Comment: It is unclear what do you need. Please describe tables with columns and write what do you want to change.

Comment: I just need to have TODAY DATE as reference because I use it in WHERE conditions, for example `where MyTable.Date >= @Today`. If I use `where MyTable.Date >= GetDate()` I don't get correct results, since GetDate contains also time information.

Comment: MyTable.Date>=CAST(GetDate() as date) is enough.

Comment: Yes you are right, that one is also an option. The reason why I am looking for a compact version of "today without time info" is that in the same query I am may be using it several times. So imagine it is 10 times I prefer to write @Today than `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caveats. [Indeed it is the best way according to this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server/3696991#3696991)