# Convert a SQL Server datetime to a shorter date format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a `datetime` column in SQL Server that gives me data like this `10/27/2010 12:57:49 pm` and I want to query this column but just have SQL Server return the day month and year - eg. `2010 10 27` or something like that.

What are the functions I should be researching?

Should I be trying to convert to another date data type? Or simply convert it to a string?

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx Specifically > Date and Time Styles

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server?? SQL Server 2008 introduced a load of new date and time related datatypes, e.g. `DATE` - so if you're on 2008, you can use `SELECT CAST(YourDateTimeColumn AS DATE)` and you get back just the date - no time portion.

Comment: @marc_s http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314561/are-votes-to-a-question-comment-more-valuable-than-votes-for-an-answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the time portion of a datetime value (SQL Server)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/how-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Have a look at [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). The 3rd parameter is the date time style you want to convert to.

e.g.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) -- dd/MM/yyyy format
```

Comment: It seems that 106 is "dd mon yy"
and "dd/MM/yyyy" is 103

Comment: @nahab You are correct. Also, I had to use varchar(11) instead of varchar(10) to prevent the year to be shortened (eg. I saw 195 instead of 1953)

Comment: Also, you can use 101 if you want the results formatted mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 64):

Try this:

`print cast(getdate() as date )`

Comment: I like this option more than the accepted answer. It leaves the column in a Date format so that my 'order by' works correctly instead of just a varchar.

Comment: This does not work on SQL Server 2005 and earlier. The DATE data type was introduced with SQL 2008.

Comment: As stated above it is indeed nice to get a date data-type, but when a specific format is expected (like "dd MM yyyy") then more is needed.

Answer (score 15):

If you need the result in a date format you can use:

```
Select Convert(DateTime, Convert(VarChar, GetDate(), 101))
```

Answer (score 11):

In addition to CAST and CONVERT, if you are using Sql Server 2008, you can convert to a date type (or use that type to start with), and then optionally convert again to a varchar:

```
declare @myDate date
set @myDate = getdate()
print cast(@myDate as varchar(10))
```

output:

```
2012-01-17
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have a **datetime** field that gives the results like this 2018-03-30 08:43:28.177

**Proposed:**   and you want to change the **datetime** to **date** to appear like 2018-03-30

```
cast(YourDateField as Date)
```

Comment: you haven't added anything new, jabu.hlong already gave this answer 4 years ago...

Comment: It is not assured that the date will be rendered in the OP's format. It might be yyyy-MM-dd, dd/MM/yyyy, dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00, or still something else.

Answer (score 6):

With SQL Server 2005, I would use this:

```
select replace(convert(char(10),getdate(),102),'.',' ')
```

> Results: 2015 03 05

Answer (score 6):

The shortest date format of mm/dd/yy can be obtained with:

```
Select Convert(varchar(8),getdate(),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add date keyword.
E.g. select date(orderdate),count(1) from orders where orderdate > '2014-10-01' group by date(orderdate);

orderdate is in date time. 
This query will show the orders for that date rather than datetime.

Date keyword applied on a datetime column will change it to short date.

Answer (score 0):

For any versions of SQL Server: **dateadd**(dd, **datediff**(dd, 0, **getdate**()), 0)

Comment: It is not assured that the date will be rendered in the OP's format. It might be yyyy-MM-dd, dd/MM/yyyy, dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00, or still something else.

Answer (score 0):

The original DateTime field : [_Date_Time]

The converted to Shortdate  : 'Short_Date'

```
CONVERT(date, [_Date_Time]) AS 'Short_Date'
```

Comment: This returns a date data type which will be left to the interface to render as a string, so it may well produce "27/12/2018 00:00:00". That's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: This what he aimed to get  -- dd/MM/yyyy  ;
and this what my answer produces 2018-11-20

Comment: Well first of all 2018-11-20 is *not* dd/MM/yyyy but yyyy-MM-dd. But the rendering is really system (and locale) dependent. On my system it produces also hours, minutes and seconds (all zero). This is because you did not tell SQL how the date should be represented as string, and the OP needs an exact string format.

Comment: Firstly, 2018-11-20 is because my PC is configured for Arabic language use ;
Secondly, i will try it after changing the short date in my PC