# Cast datetime as date still shows time

Tags: sql, datetime, casting, sql-server-2008-r2, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to cast my datetime as date to get rid of the time, but the query results still show the time.  When I compare with what I see [online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901161/convert-a-sql-server-datetime-to-a-shorter-date-format), it looks correct.

How do I fix it?

```
..
, CAST("Process"."StartDate" AS date)
..
```

The result still shows like this:

```
4/14/2019 0:00
```

Update: I'm trying to use convert, as suggested below, but I'm getting Exception calling "fill" with "1" arguments.

There's probably something wrong with my syntax for the convert.  Any ideas?  All the online examples I see use datetime with convert. The complete query in powershell looks like this:

```
$SQLquery_Proc = @"
SELECT DISTINCT 
   Process.Process_ID
   ,"Process"."ProcessName"
   ,ProcessFacilities = STUFF(
                 (SELECT ',' + apf.FacCode FROM ProcessFacilities apf where apf.Process_ID = "Process"."Process_ID"  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
               ) 
   , "People"."Last_Name"
   , "People"."First_Name"
   , "People"."Middle_Initial"
   , "People"."Degree"
   , "Process"."P_ID"
   , "People_Facilities_ALL"."FacCode" as "People_FacCode"
   , "People_Facilities_ALL"."Current_status"
   , "People_Facilities_ALL"."Status_category"
   , convert("People_Facilities_ALL"."Status_from_date", 101)  --issue?
   , convert("People_Facilities_ALL"."Next_r_date", 101)        --issue?
FROM   
   Process 
   left JOIN "DB"."dbo"."People" ON "Process"."PRACT_ID"="People"."P_ID" 
   left JOIN "DB"."dbo"."People_Facilities_ALL" ON "Process"."P_ID"="People_Facilities_ALL"."PRACT_ID" 
   ORDER BY 
   "People"."P_ID"
"@
```

Update2:
I figured out how to get convert to work. Thanks for the help!

```
, convert(VARCHAR(23),"People_Facilities_ALL"."Status_from_date", 101)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: It's a sql query inside a powershell script run through task manager, the results are written to an excel file.

Comment: @Michele: Nice to know but that doesn't answer the question which DBMS is used.

Comment: Do you mean SQL?  What is an example of a DBMS?  I'm sorry, I'm relatively new to certain terms.

Comment: SQL SERVER? MySQL? something else ?

Comment: Database management system. Sql server, Oracle, Sql lite...

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 or higher, relational database.

Comment: There is no dedicated date type in .NET, and hence there isn't one in PowerShell. It'll still end up as a `DateTime`. If you want to show only the date, use an appropriate format string (i.e. `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`).

Comment: *"Do you mean SQL? What is an example of a DBMS? I'm sorry, I'm relatively new to certain terms. "* @Michele SQL is just a standard from ANSI/ISO which defines the statements, Database Management System (DBMS) or also called  Relational Database Management System (RDBMS). are the products based on that standard.. Some product examples are SQL Server (MSSQL), MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle database or SQLite

Comment: sql server 2008 R2

Comment: Have a look at [Date and Time Conversions Using SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

Comment: Michele, @JeroenMostert already give you the answer

Comment: This is, as Jeroen Mostert wrote, a PowerShell issue. Your Sql Server query returns a `Date` data type, which is mapped, due to the lack of a better option, to the .Net DateTime struct. Since the .Net framework does not include a Date only type

Comment: Michele   if you can't figure it out or make it work with the suggestions. most likely it would help if you share some example data from your table and the PowerShell  code itself...

Comment: If modifying the code that reads the result is too complicated or too cumbersome, it is possible to have SQL Server output an appropriate value with `CONVERT` (e.g. `CONVERT(CHAR(10), [Process].[StartDate], 120)`. In general, this doesn't belong in a query and formatting should be left to the client code, but if this query is used only to produce results for PowerShell to write directly to a file it's halfway acceptable. Note that the type changes to a `string` if you do this, which might not end up correctly in the Excel file. Check how (typed) values get converted from PowerShell to Excel.

Comment: I'm trying the convert, that I saw in Theo's link, and Jeroen is discussing above.  I'll keep you posted.  I don't handle the query results (data result strings or rows) in my Powershell script, and I'm not using the .net plugin with powershell, so I'd rather not add that.

Comment: I added an update above.  There must be an issue with my convert that I added to the query.

Comment: I added Update2, which shows how I got convert to work.  Thanks for the help!!  :)