# How to Insert varchar data into a datetime field (SQL Server 2005)?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, varchar

I have this data I want inserted to a table. Sample data `MM/DD/YYYY` + 1 day and `12:00:00 PM`

Basically what I need is to insert the current date + 1 day and specific time of 12:00:00 PM.

My code is this:

```
DECLARE @MyEstimatedDate as varchar(100)    ---TEMPORARY CONTAINER
DECLARE @MyEstimatedDate1 as varchar(100)   ---TEMPORARY CONTAINER
DECLARE @MyEstimatedDate2 as varchar(100)   ---TEMPORARY CONTAINER
DECLARE @MyEstimatedDate3 as DATETIME       ---FINAL DATA NEEDED. This is the data I want inserted.

SET @MyEstimatedDate = DATEADD(day,1,GETDATE()) 
SET @MyEstimatedDate1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@MyEstimatedDate,101)
SET @MyEstimatedDate2 = @MyEstimatedDate1 + ' 12:00:00 PM'
SET @MyEstimatedDate3 = cast(@MyEstimatedDate2 as datetime)  ---I believe this is the error
```

Error message I get:

> *The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `varchar` when manipulating `datetime` data. SQL Server 2005 offers [enough tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for you to be able to avoid conversion.

The following is a more or less [known method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server/3696991#3696991) of dropping the time part from a `datetime` value:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @InputDateTime), 0);
```

In the above example, [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) calculates the number of days between a date specified as `0` and the given date. The number of days is then added by the [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function to the `0` date. The final result is a `datetime` value with the time of `00:00:00` and the same date as `@InputDateTime`. This is because the `0` date is an integer representation of `1900-01-01 00:00:00`: its time part is zero and, since we have incremented it by a whole number of days, so is the result's time part.

Now, if instead of the `DATEDIFF` days you add `DATEDIFF+1`, you will get the next day. Furthermore, if instead of `0` as the date to be incremented you use `12:00`, you will get the next day's noon, which appears to be what you want. So, the final expression will look like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @InputDateTime) + 1, '12:00');
```

Since your input timestamp is supposed to be the current date & time, just replace `@InputDateTime` with `GETDATE()`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, '12:00');
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you for the complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do

```
cast(dateadd(day, 1, getdate()) as date)
```

that was for midnight.  For noon, do this

```
dateadd(hour, 12, cast(cast(dateadd(day, 1, getdate()) as date) as datetime))
```

forget the above, it's wrong.

Correct answer is

```
dateadd(hour, 12, cast(cast(dateadd(day, 1, getdate()) as date) as datetime))
```

This time I even tested it.

Comment: I got this output: '2/10/2013 11:58:28 PM'. I need the output to be like this instead 2/10/2013 12:00:00 PM

Comment: My revised answer gives me 2013-02-11 12:00:00.000.   The format is a function of the local setup and mine is different than yours.  However, the value is correct.

Comment: Thanks but i got this output: '2/12/2013 12:38:00 PM'. I need a standard output to be like this '2/12/2013 12:00:00 PM'. The 12:00:00 PM is constant.

Comment: you can't use date in mssql 2005

Comment: This is what I used: dateadd(hour, 12, cast(cast(dateadd(day, 1, getdate()) as datetime) as datetime)) and got this output '2/12/2013 12:38:00 PM'. I need the time part to be 12:00:00 PM.

Answer (score 0):

datetime type contains date + time. In your case for @MyEstimatedDate1 need just a date

```
DECLARE @MyEstimatedDate varchar(100)    ---TEMPORARY CONTAINER
DECLARE @MyEstimatedDate1 varchar(100)   ---TEMPORARY CONTAINER
DECLARE @MyEstimatedDate2 varchar(100)   ---TEMPORARY CONTAINER
DECLARE @MyEstimatedDate3 DATETIME       ---FINAL DATA NEEDED. This is the data I want inserted.

SET @MyEstimatedDate = DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()) 
SET @MyEstimatedDate1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CAST(@MyEstimatedDate AS date), 101)
SET @MyEstimatedDate2 = @MyEstimatedDate1 + ' 12:00:00 PM'
SET @MyEstimatedDate3 = cast(@MyEstimatedDate2 as datetime)   ---I believ
```

OR simple to use it

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour, 36, GETDATE() - CAST(GETDATE() AS time))
```