# How to only keep the time portion of a datetime value (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, date-conversion

Here's what I use to get a `HH:MM` string:

```
CONVERT(varchar(5), time_requested, 108)
```

I'm thinking there may be a more elegant way, even maybe more efficient (see similar question on [How to remove the time portion of a datetime value (SQL Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/how-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server)).

Requirements:

- the final result has to be easily convertible to a string (in order to be able to concatenate some field `time_created` with a field such as `date_created`).
- the following 2 cases must be covered: `HH:MM` and `HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: `CONVERT(varchar(5), time_requested, 108)` I think as per your 1st requirement this is most elegant solution. Which version of `SQL  SERVER` you are using

Comment: Using 2008 and 2012...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Declare @D datetime = GetDate()      -- Data Type could be Time as well

Select CONVERT(varchar(8), @D, 108)  -- for HH:MM:SS  11:27:26
Select CONVERT(varchar(5), @D, 108)  -- for HH:MM     11:27
```

Failed to mention, if 2012+ you could also use Format()

```
Declare @D DateTime = '2016-10-22 13:30:25'

Select Format(@D,'HH:mm')         -- 13:30
Select Format(@D,'hh:mm:ss tt')   -- 01:30:25 PM
```

Comment: Didn't know about Format. Thx!

Comment: @user3341592  It is a great function with many options, HOWEVER, the performance on large data-sets is horrible

Answer (score 4):

Your method is fine. It produces a string representation of the value.

You can also convert to a `time` data type:

```
select cast(time_requested as time)
```

But note that this is "format-less" -- it contains hours, minutes, seconds, and fractions of seconds. So, your method is probably the better approach.